# Aggregation by group not returning the correct value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where inside the same product code, there is a duplicate date as follow:

[image: Dataframe]

In order to correct these duplicate datetimes by-products, I tried to aggregate by-product ('cod_interno' column)  and date('data' column).

```
df = df.groupby(['cod_interno', 'data']).agg({'descrição_produto': 'first',
                                'unidade_lojas': 'first',
                                'cod_fornecedor': 'first',
                                'leadtime': 'first',
                                'descr_fornecedor': 'first',
                                'entrada': sum,
                                'saida': sum,
                                'saldo_atual': 'last'})
```

```
11  504777  Arroz Prato Fino 1kg Tp1    1   135828.0    Arroz Prato Fino    11.0    24/01/2018  7980.00     0.0        2.0   27.0
12  504777  Arroz Prato Fino 1kg Tp1    1   135828.0    Arroz Prato Fino    11.0    24/01/2018  119700.00   30.0       0.0  57.0
```

The duplicate date row is:

```
11  504777  Arroz Prato Fino 1kg Tp1    1   135828.0    Arroz Prato Fino    11.0    24/01/2018  7980.00     0.0        2.0   27.0
12  504777  Arroz Prato Fino 1kg Tp1    1   135828.0    Arroz Prato Fino    11.0    24/01/2018  119700.00   30.0       0.0  57.0
```

**My expected result is:**

**entrada** : To sum : 0 + 30

**saida**: To sum : 2 + 0

**saldo_atual** : Keep the last: 57

**other columns**: Keep the first

```
12  504777  Arroz Prato Fino 1kg Tp1    1   135828.0    Arroz Prato Fino    11.0    24/01/2018  119700.00   30.0       2    57.0
```

However my result was completely different:

entrada :  150

saida:  59

saldo_atual : 125

Comment: Have you tried to verify that there are only those two records sharing the same `cod_interno`, `data`?

Comment: You are correct. I had to add the Cost Centre.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chun Kit Yeung proposed, it was missing

```
df = df.groupby(['cod_interno', 'data', 'unidade_lojas']).agg({'descrição_produto': 'first',
                                'cod_fornecedor': 'first',
                                'leadtime': 'first',
                                'descr_fornecedor': 'first',
                                'entrada': sum,
                                'saida': sum,
                                'saldo_atual': 'last'})
```